# How can I replace values in a row in my csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, one-hot-encoding

I need to perform one-hot encoding on a CSV file. I've already successfully converted null values to zero in the CSV data. Here's a sample of my CSV data:

csv:

```
malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,packed with UPX,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,inspect load icon resource,reference analysis tools strings,0
```

The issue I'm facing is that I'm struggling to convert all the features of the malware to one-hot encoding. The goal is to check if a feature is present in the header and, if so, convert it to one.

I have created an array called headers containing all possible features of malware, which also correspond to the headers of my CSV:

> headers = [
> "label",
> "md5",
> "create new key via CryptAcquireContext",
> "delete user account group",
> # ... and so on ]

How can I convert all the data in my CSV that matches the headers in the headers array to a value of one, essentially achieving the following transformation?

For example, this line from the CSV:

```
malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to perform this one-hot encoding based on the headers and create a new CSV file with the encoded values. This means that all features in header will be 1

Code I've Tried:

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define a function to read headers from a text file


def headers():
    headers = []

    output_file = "feature-list.txt"
    csv_input_file = "cleaned-features.csv.csv"
    csv_output_file = "headers-features.csv"

    # Read the headers from the text file
    with open(output_file, 'r') as txt_file:
        for line in txt_file:
            line = line.strip()  # Remove trailing newline characters
            headers.append(line)

    # Add the additional headers
    headers.insert(1, "md5")
    headers.insert(0, "label")

    # Read the existing CSV data
    existing_data = []
    with open(csv_input_file, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        existing_data = list(csv_reader)

    # Add the headers to the existing data
    existing_data.insert(0, headers)

    # Write the headers and data to the CSV file
    with open(csv_output_file, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerows(existing_data)`

# Define a function to replace null values with zero
`def zero():
    headers = []
    output_file = "feature-list.txt"

    # Read the headers from the text file
    with open(output_file, 'r') as txt_file:
        for line in txt_file:
            line = line.strip()  # Remove trailing newline characters
            headers.append(line)

    # Define the headers you want to check for
    headers_to_check = headers  # Replace with your actual headers

    # Read the input CSV file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv("headers-features.csv")

    # Iterate through the headers you want to check
    for header in headers_to_check:
        # Create a new column for each header and fill it with 'null' for rows without a value
        df[header] = df.apply(lambda row: row[header] if header in row else 'null', axis=1)
        df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        df.to_csv("zero.csv", index=False)
```

```
Inpput: malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,packed with UPX,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,inspect load icon resource,reference analysis tools
```

Desired Output:

```
Inpput: malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,1,1
```

I need to make a function to ensure features are covernted to one in a new csv file!

How to achieve this one-hot encoding based on the headers in Python?